# UICollectionView and UIView into UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I need to know how to do to embed a UICollectionView and a UIView within a UIScrollView, but that everything moves with the scroll of UIScrollview.

the layout is something like the following image:

[image: Layout]

Comment: You can use **UITableView**. Add view in header as par use and use cell for collectionView. **UITableView** manage your memory if you use reusable cell in both **tableView** and **UICollectionView**

Comment: @ShardaPrasad That way, no, I'm going to add a pagerAdapter before the UICollectionView, I think with the UITableView it can not.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `view` as the `collectionView`'s section supplementary view (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618037-collectionview))? It will become part of the `collectionView` thus scrolling of the `collectionView` will handle also the `view` itself.

Comment: Because I'm going to add a pagerAdapter and I think that does not support it, that's why I want to do it that way

Answer (score 0):

1- Drag a `UIScrollview` to your vc give it leading , trailing , top and bottom constraints to the parent view

2- Drag a UIView (content-view) in side the scrollview , give it leading , trailing , top and bottom constraints to the scrollview

3- Control drag from the content-view to the main outer view and select **Equal-Widths**

4- Drag `UIView` inside the content-view  give it leading , trailing , top and a height say 300

5-  Drag `UIcollectionView` below the top-view  give it leading , trailing to the content-View ,  top to the top-View and a height as you want

6- Hook bottom constraint of the collectionview to the bottom of the content-View

7- set bounces property of the collectionView to false

**note:** You may hook the height constraint of the collection-view and change in runtime , also it's better to use tableView instead of collection view in presenting data vertically

Comment: this This answer is the most complete, between the UIView and the UICollectionView I am going to add a PagerAdapter, so I do not use the headers because I do not think it supports that.

Comment: This method not run! :(

Comment: Can you explain me better?

Comment: which step u stuck in

Comment: I try to understand your steps but I do not get it right, it does not work. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: please be more specific go through steps and ask for something within it

Comment: I follow the steps and the view goes blank. I do not know why!