# Why doesn't my uicollectionview move with the underlying uiscrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a simple iOS app built in Xcode 9.2, written in Swift 4. I have a working, vertical scroll view with a working, horizontally-scrolling collection view placed on top of it.  Scrolling works as I'd like, except that the collection view does not move with the rest of the content when scrolling vertically (see screenshots, where collection view stays in same absolute position, whether scrolled to top or bottom of underlying view).

[image: screenshot: scrolled to the top]

[image: screenshot: scrolled to the bottom]

[image: screenshot: views hierarchy]

I tried following the steps in the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692425/uicollectionview-and-uiview-into-uiscrollview), but when I add constraints to the collection view as described, the collection view stops appearing in the simulation and vertical scrolling stops working.

If possible, I would like to have the collection view move up and down with the rest of the content when scrolling.

Comment: show your constraints, they are the source of your trouble

Answer (score 0):

Probably a problem in your constraints :

1. Remove all your constraints and let auto-layout do the job
2. Try to remove the view between your scrollView and your collectionView.

Super-tips: Put background colors to your views, it will allow you to debug in a better way.

**Edit:**

1. Add your UIScrollView to your Superview and set the four constraints (leading / trailing / top / bottom).
2. Add an UIView to the Scrollview; set the four constraints to the Scrollview and set a backgroundColor to the UIView in case you need to debug
3. Add the "equal width" + "equal height" constraints between your UIView and the Scrollview
4. Add any elements you want to the last created UIView
5. Run the app, all your items should be able to scroll.
6. Add the final missing constraints for auto-layout to work fine:

   - all the elements inside your UIView should have leading+trailing constraints to the UIView (center horizontally can also be a good alternative)
   - Put vertical constraints between your elements, starting from the top. In your case, the "top" label has a "top constraint" to UIView and the "bottom" label has a "bottom constraint" to UIView.
   - Set height constraints on your items so the scrollview has a contentSize

Here's a screenshot of the result :

[image: xcode screenshot]

Comment: if he removes all his constraints, what should the autolayout use to do its job?

Comment: Yes I meant the "add constraints" tool in storyboard / xib. Actually don't know how to call it

Comment: that does not make any sense

Comment: @Cerise I tried removing the view between them and it broke vertical scrolling.  I also tried letting IB "add missing constraints" (with intermediate view put back in place) and it didn't change behavior from what I showed with screenshots above.

Comment: @Cerise I followed your directions as-stated with one change: I had to make the UIView height greater than the scroll view to get it to scroll vertically.  At that point, the UIView would scroll between top and bottom, but the collection would stay in-place on the screen.  When I added constraints between all the elements as you described, the collection view disappeared from the simulator.  Still struggling to solve this problem.

Comment: Here's a link to a video showing what I'm seeing [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lCk-xu7gGn3uh1dZdE1ZQo1PUsXmfOZl)

Comment: Strange, can you upload an example project on github ?